# CAB "check" button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

How can we handle the check button in the CAB menu?

Is the item associated to some internal id like android.R.id.checkbox?

I've read that it could be handled in SherlockActionBar CAB, but could it be the same with the native ActionBar CAB?

Is there any way to detect the interaction of this item? **onActionModeFinished()** is not sufficient since I'm calling it multiple times since the CAB needs to be present due to previous changes that happened.

Thanks.

Comment: Looking for this myself.  No one has any input yet?

Comment: Could someone tell me what CAB stands for?

Comment: @WarrenFaith it stands for Contextual Action Bar.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for telling me. This abbreviation was unknown for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,  finally found a solution after trying some things.
Place the code you want for the checkbox or onbackpressed in the method below

```
 public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) 
{
     //place the code you want for the checkbox or back icon here.  If you don't want
     // this code run if other selections are used, then just create a boolean value that
    //you earlier on and check the value in this section before implementing the code
}
```

};

Comment: hey, this is not the best solution, apparently this part is called in many other cases, like in mine I have a delete(dustbing) on the right, and its called then too. Will update if I find a better solution.